# Not showing smily ( Emoji ) in in UITextView in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist, emoji

I have stored all uni-codes(emoji characters) in plist supported by iphone. When i write directly as

```
- (IBAction)sendButtonSelected:(id)sender {
NSMutableArray *emoticonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"\ue415",nil];
NSString *imageNameToPass = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[emoticonsArray objectAtIndex:0]];
NSLog(@"imageNameToPass1...%@",imageNameToPass);
messageTextView.text =imageNameToPass;
 }
```

it show emoji in textview but as soon as i fetch from plist

```
NSString *plistPath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"unicodes" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath1];
activeArray= [dictionary objectForKey:categoryString];

NSLog(@"activeArray...%@",activeArray);

emoticonsArrayForHomeEmoji = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[activeArray count]];
for(int i=0; i<[activeArray count]; i++)
{
    id objects = (id)[activeArray objectAtIndex:i];
    [emoticonsArrayForHomeEmoji insertObject:objects atIndex:i];
}
NSString *imageNameToPass = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[emoticonsArrayForHomeEmoji 
objectAtIndex:0]];
NSLog(@"imageNameToPass1...%@",imageNameToPass);
messageTextView.text =imageNameToPass;
```

then it shows unicode as text \ue415 in text view instead of emoji.

What i am doing wrong?. Please help me out!

Comment: And your Xcode-related question is? (Oh, or another misuse of the Xcode tag? Guess for how long I do iOS development without Xcode? Two years, yeah...)

Comment: @H2CO3: You mean i do not use xcode tag while asking question like this.

Comment: @ketanrajput XCode is completely irrelevant to programming for iPhone unless you have an XCode specific problem. For some reason people do not understand this and it is incredibly frustrating because it takes all meaning out of the XCode tag.

Comment: @sosborn: ya i have edited the tag. I guess its relevant. Is it?

Comment: I have posted the whole steps take a look at it, hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\uxxxx` notation is only interpreted by the compiler (as the source code is usually in ASCII or MacRoman or whatever but not often UTF8)

Plist files uses the characters directly, and are encoded in UTF8.
So you should insert the emoji character itself into the plist directly, instead of using the `\uxxxx` notation, as the Plist data will be read as-is.

Lion and Mountain Lion [Keyboard palettes contains emoji characters directly](http://www.osxfacile.com/Multimedia/Images/palette3.jpg), so that should not be difficult to insert the characters when editing the PLIST anyway.

Comment: thanks alot! I just drag the emojis to plist and it worked for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Wel said by @AliSoftware, the Plist data will be read as-it is, so you can add the emojis to your plist by following this steps:

1) Go to your top bar, and click on Edit.

2) Now select Special Characters

3) Now drag and drop emoji to plist.

For more details I am adding snap shots. take a look at it.[image: Step No. 1][image: Step No. 2][image: Step No. 3]