# How to build and show Emoji Sticker on iOS?

Tags: ios, webview, gif

Many Messager apps can show animated stickers, any idea of how those sticker is build and shown on screen ?

My guess is either stickers are GIFs or NSArray of animated UIImage.

Second part of the question is how to properly display those stickers ?

A UIWebView can display GIFs, but seems a overkill. What other solutions for displaying these small GIF/Stickers ?

Thanks !!

Comment: just see below link..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691083/not-showing-smily-emoji-in-in-uitextview-in-ios..


u might get your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`-[UIImage animatedImageNamed:duration:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/animatedImageNamed%3aduration%3a) and its siblings.