# want to add stickers(similar to emoji) to textview in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6

I am trying to make my emoji keyboard as default keyboard.I
 want to add my images (sticker) to the textview.I am using xcode6 that allow to make our keyboard as default keyboard for all app.I can add text to the textview when click on my sticker.but not able to add that sticker to my textview.

In short,I am trying to get access of textview to add images.

Your solutions are appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691083/not-showing-smily-emoji-in-in-uitextview-in-ios

Comment: no,I am not using any unicode \uxxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use NSAttributted String:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"like after"];

NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"];

NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];

[attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(4, 1) withAttributedString:attrStringWithImage];
```

source: [iOS 7 TextKit - How to insert images inline with text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930462/ios-7-textkit-how-to-insert-images-inline-with-text)

Comment: I have used the below code.it will add only 1 image  and lost the previous one .                            
    [attributedString appendAttributedString:attrStringWithImage];